# How to make nested Accordion?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

In semantic_ui-react library exists component [Accordion](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion#accordion-example-nested). There are some examples, but I have to make nested accordion, which has structure:

```
-accordion:
    -sub_accordion1
    -sub_accordion2
    -sub_accordion3
```

I saw there is example of nested accordion with panels, but I don't want to put accordions into the panels. I tried so:

```
export default class AccordionExampleStandard extends Component {
  state = { activeIndex: 0 }

  handleClick = (e, titleProps) => {
    const { index } = titleProps
    const { activeIndex } = this.state
    const newIndex = activeIndex === index ? -1 : index

    this.setState({ activeIndex: newIndex })
  }

  render() {
    const { activeIndex } = this.state

    return (
      <Accordion>
        <Accordion.Title active={activeIndex === 0} index={0} onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <Icon name='dropdown' />
          What is a dog?
        </Accordion.Title>
        <Accordion.Content active={activeIndex === 0}>
          <Accordion.Title active={activeIndex === 1} index={1} onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <Icon name='dropdown' />
          What kinds of dogs are there?
        </Accordion.Title>
        <Accordion.Content active={activeIndex === 1}>
          Content1
        </Accordion.Content>

        <Accordion.Title active={activeIndex === 2} index={2} onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <Icon name='dropdown' />
          How do you acquire a dog?
        </Accordion.Title>
        <Accordion.Content active={activeIndex === 2}>
          Content2
        </Accordion.Content>
<Accordion.Title active={activeIndex === 3} index={3} onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <Icon name='dropdown' />
          What kinds of dogs are there?
        </Accordion.Title>
        <Accordion.Content active={activeIndex === 3}>
         Content3
        </Accordion.Content>
        </Accordion.Content>
      </Accordion>
    )
  }
}
```

It renders component, but I can collapse only main accordion and can't collapse it's children. How can I perform this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you need a simple solution, it is better to use `panels` because they seem to automatically manipulate the `activeIndex` which is the main attribute that decides the expansion and collapse of the accordion. If you were to do it yourself like above you need to maintain all the hierarchy and manipulate yourself by adjusting state in the `onClick` handler. So, if your use case is not custom or complex you can try something like below.

Here is a working demo [**NESTED ACCORDION SEMANTIC UI**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-accordion-semantic-ui?file=style.css)

```
import { Accordion } from 'semantic-ui-react';

const AccordionContent = (content) => (
  <div className="indent">
    {content}
  </div>
)

const SubAccordion1Panels = [
  {
    title: 'Sub Accordion 11',
    content: { content: AccordionContent('11 Content'), key: '11-content'} ,
    key: 'sub-accordion-11'
  }, {
    title: 'Sub Accordion 12',
    content: { content: AccordionContent('12 Contents'), key: '12-content' },
    key: 'sub-accordion-12'
  }, {
    title: 'Sub Accordion 13',
    content: { content: AccordionContent('13 Contents'), key: '13-content' },
    key: 'sub-accordion-13'
  },
]

const SubAccordion1Content = (
  <div className="indent">
    <Accordion.Accordion
      style={{marginLeft: "20px"}}
      className="no-padding"
      panels={SubAccordion1Panels}
    />
  </div>
)

const SubAccordionPanels = [
  {
    title: 'Sub Accordion 1',
    content: { content: SubAccordion1Content, key: 'sa1-content' },
    key: 'sub-accordion-1'
  }, {
    title: 'Sub Accordion 2',
    content: { content: AccordionContent('SA2 Content'), key: 'sa2-content' },
    key: 'sub-accordion-2'
  }, {
    title: 'Sub Accordion 3',
    content: { content: AccordionContent('SA3 Content'), key: 'sa3-content' },
    key: 'sub-accordion-3'
  }
]

const SubAccordions = (
  <div className="indent">
    <Accordion.Accordion
      className="no-padding"
      panels={SubAccordionPanels}
    />
  </div>
)

const AccordionPanels = [
  { title: 'Accordion', content: { content: SubAccordions, key: 'sub-accordions' } },
]

const AccordionExampleNested = () => (
  <Accordion
    defaultActiveIndex={0}
    panels={AccordionPanels}
  />
)

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AccordionExampleNested />
    )
  }
}
```

Also for the indentation, you need to override the default css

```
.indent {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.no-padding {
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to make a nested accordion:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Accordion } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const level1Panels = [
  { title: 'Level 1A', content: 'Level 1A Contents' },
  { title: 'Level 1B', content: 'Level 1B Contents' },
]

const Level1Content = (
  <div>
    Welcome to level 1
    <Accordion.Accordion panels={level1Panels} />
  </div>
)

const level2Panels = [
  { title: 'Level 2A', content: 'Level 2A Contents' },
  { title: 'Level 2B', content: 'Level 2B Contents' },
]

const Level2Content = (
  <div>
    Welcome to level 2
    <Accordion.Accordion panels={level2Panels} />
  </div>
)

const rootPanels = [
  { title: 'Level 1', content: { content: Level1Content, key: 'content-1' } },
  { title: 'Level 2', content: { content: Level2Content, key: 'content-2'         } },
]

const AccordionExampleNested = () => (
  <Accordion defaultActiveIndex={0} panels={rootPanels} styled />
)

export default AccordionExampleNested
```

Comment: Maybe he have missed the docs, beacause the proposed snipped works out of the box.

Comment: I saw this snippet and I wrote in answer, that I needn't to make panel-accordion. I need to make simple,without panels. in this snippet we see "panels={rootPanels}"

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version of this. Its a recursive Accordion inside Accordion inside Accordion (infinitely).

Its also on CodePen https://codepen.io/codeman1293/pen/OJWppQM?editors=1111

```
console.clear();
const ButtonToolbar = ReactBootstrap.ButtonToolbar;
const Button = ReactBootstrap.Button;
const Jumbotron = ReactBootstrap.Jumbotron;
const Accordion = ReactBootstrap.Accordion;
const Panel = ReactBootstrap.Panel;

var baseItems = [
  { id: 1, title: "Land", body: "", parentId: 0 },
  { id: 2, title: "Sea", body: "Submarine", parentId: 0 },
  {
    id: 8,
    title: "Air",
    body: "Helicopter<br />Aeroplanes<br />Drones",
    parentId: 0
  },
  { id: 3, title: "Cars", body: "", parentId: 1 },
  { id: 4, title: "Vans", body: "Transit<br />Sprinter", parentId: 1 },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: "Boats",
    body: "Speedboat<br />Fishing Boat<br />Dinghy",
    parentId: 2
  },
  { id: 6, title: "Petrol", body: "", parentId: 3 },
  { id: 7, title: "Automatic", body: "", parentId: 6 },
  { id: 9, title: "2.0L", body: "BMW X3<br />Mercedes GLC<br />Audi Q5", parentId: 7 }
];

const App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    const RecursiveAccordion = ({ items, recurse = false }) => {
      return (
        <Accordion>
          {items.map((item, index) => {
            var children = baseItems.filter((i) => {
              return i.parentId === item.id;
            });

            var hasChildren = children.length > 0;

            if (item.parentId === 0) {
              return (
                <Panel header={item.title} eventKey={index}>
                  {hasChildren && (
                    <div>
                      <RecursiveAccordion items={children} recurse={true} />
                      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.body }} />
                    </div>
                  )}
                  {!hasChildren && (
                    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.body }} />
                  )}
                </Panel>
              );
            }

            if (recurse) {
              return (
                <Panel header={item.title} eventKey={index}>
                  {hasChildren && (
                    <div>
                      <RecursiveAccordion items={children} recurse={true} />
                      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.body }} />
                    </div>
                  )}
                  {!hasChildren && (
                    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.body }} />
                  )}
                </Panel>
              );
            }
          })}
        </Accordion>
      );
    };

    return <RecursiveAccordion items={baseItems} recurse={false} />;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```