# Is there a way to create a dynamic state and setState in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the following deceleration:
  `const [open1, setOpen1] = useState(false);`

and would like to generate this as many as I fetch records from the database (for every record fetched ) I need new                                                                                                              [open, setopen]

here is my for loop used in my code.

````
        <Container fluid={true} className="text-center">
          <div
            className="questionrectangle "
            onClick={() => setOpen1(!open1)}
            name="step-one"
            aria-controls="example-collapse-text"
            aria-expanded={open1}>
            <p className="questiontext "> {post.QString}</p>
          </div>
          <Collapse in={open1} name="step-two">
            <p className="questionanswer">{post.Answer}</p>
          </Collapse>
        </Container> ```

If you have any idea I would be appreciated
````

Comment: That not a very good idea. Why don't you want deal with `setOpen` only once in the `Container` ?

Comment: When i use it only one time, it affects the other elements. i mean all elements collapse together when i press on one of them.

Comment: Right, you'll have to setup a prop with a unique id. Then, your effect would apply to the specific child `Collapse` component with that id.

Comment: I'll try that.Thank you.

Comment: you should outsource the fetched data into a component and have the setopen state there so that each fetched item has its own state... thats how the flow of react works

Comment: although this is an Accordion, you may find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47926843/how-to-make-nested-accordion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create separate component to hold 'open' state. Something like this..

```
function QuestionAnswer({post}) {
  const [open1, setOpen1] = useState(true);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="questionrectangle "
        onClick={() => setOpen1(!open1)}
        name="step-one"
        aria-controls="example-collapse-text"
        aria-expanded={open1}
      >
        <p className="questiontext "> {post.QString}</p>
      </div>
      {open1 && (
        <div name="step-two">
          <p className="questionanswer">{post.Answer}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Now, from your main application fetch the data and create one component for each Post - like this

```
  // Replace this with fetch request
  const data = [
    { QString: "Question 1", Answer: "answer 1" },
    { QString: "Question 2", Answer: "answer 2" },
    { QString: "Question 3", Answer: "answer 3" }
  ];

  return (
    <Container fluid={true} className="text-center">
      {data.map((post) => (
        <QuestionAnswer post={post} />
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Now, each component will hold its own copy of 'Open' state and will be able to handle individual open and close state.

You can see complete sample

https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-surf-ejron

Answer (score 0):

The trick to thinking about this is that each child element (your list of <Containers />) shouldn't be responsible for knowing about their siblings, or how to responsibly manage the open state between them without causing conflicts. That responsibility should be one level higher, something that can see all the children and manage it for them.

Should be easy to adopt that accordion example for your own use.

```
const DocsManager = () => {
  // Manage which step is open here, at a higher level
  const [openIndex, setOpenIndex] = useState(0); // or whatever the default should be
  // Records could live here, or be passed in as props
  const [docs, setDocs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getDocs.then(setDocs);
  }, [])

  return docs.map((doc, i) =>
    <YourComponent
      isOpen={openIndex === i}
      // Or maybe
      open={() => setOpenIndex(i)}
      // Or maybe
      close={() => setOpenIndex(null)}
      // Or maybe
      next={() => setOpenIndex(openIndex + 1)}
      doc={doc}
    />
  );
};
```